# Can I add <p></p> tags around text content in XML elements using XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm currently putting together a dynamic HTML template facilitated by a simple document combination of XML data and *XSLT (1.0)* but I've recently come across a problem which I'd appreciate some advice on.

Having established a connection between my XML and XSLT documents, I've been using the standard `<xsl:value-of select="xxxxxx/xxxxxx"/>` command to draw out text nodes held within my XML elements and output these on to the HTML template. Great!

However, I have encountered an issue with this process.

One of my XML elements (in this example `<synopsis></synopsis>`) contains a large amount of text, currently separated by line breaks, which ideally I need to render into (three individual) paragraphs on my HTML page.

Let me share the **XML Data** example with you:

```
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>1997</year>
    <price>3.99</price>
    <publisher>Bloomsbury (UK)</publisher>
    <synopsis>
         Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone is the first novel in the Harry Potter series and J. K. Rowling's debut novel. 

         The plot follows Harry Potter, a young wizard who discovers his magical heritage as he makes close friends and a few enemies in his first year at the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. 

         With the help of his friends, Harry faces an attempted comeback by the dark wizard Lord Voldemort, who killed Harry's parents, but failed to kill Harry when he was just a year old.
   </synopsis>
 </book>
 <book>
    <title>The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo</title>
    <author>Stieg Larsson</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>5.99</price>
    <publisher>Norstedts Förlag (SWE)</publisher>
    <synopsis>
         In Stockholm, Sweden, journalist Mikael Blomkvist, co-owner of Millennium magazine, has lost a libel case brought against him by businessman Hans-Erik Wennerström. Lisbeth Salander, a brilliant but troubled investigator and hacker, compiles an extensive background check on Blomkvist for business magnate Henrik Vanger, who has a special task for him. 

         In exchange for the promise of damning information about Wennerström, Blomkvist agrees to investigate the disappearance and assumed murder of Henrik's grandniece, Harriet, 40 years ago. 

         After moving to the Vanger family's compound, Blomkvist uncovers a notebook containing a list of names and numbers that no one has been able to decipher.
    </synopsis>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

When using the `<xsl:value-of select="xxxxxx/xxxxxx"/>` command, my current output for the `<synopsis></synopsis>` elements is obviously a continual block of text without spaces (between the three paragraphs); *Harry Potter* example:

```
    Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone is the first novel in the Harry Potter series and J. K. Rowling's debut novel.The plot follows Harry Potter, a young wizard who discovers his magical heritage as he makes close friends and a few enemies in his first year at the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.With the help of his friends, Harry faces an attempted comeback by the dark wizard Lord Voldemort, who killed Harry's parents, but failed to kill Harry when he was just a year old.
```

What I'd like to achieve in my HTML output (hopefully facilitated by a template in XLST 1.0) is:

```
    <p>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone is the first novel in the Harry Potter series and J. K. Rowling's debut novel.</p>

    <p>The plot follows Harry Potter, a young wizard who discovers his magical heritage as he makes close friends and a few enemies in his first year at the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.</p>

    <p>With the help of his friends, Harry faces an attempted comeback by the dark wizard Lord Voldemort, who killed Harry's parents, but failed to kill Harry when he was just a year old.</p>
```

So here's my main question. Can the solution (above) be achieved via some form of a template in my XSLT (1.0) file? Is this even possible to do?

Could I potentially setup a string variable (of `<synopsis>`) and then search through it and find each full stop/line break within the text passage and at these points wrap `<p></p>` tags around this part of the string selection to form my paragraphs?

If this is indeed a prospect, I'd like to build on it in the future and maybe add in some further HTML tags, such as `<ol><li><li></ol>` etc.

Any help or advice on whether this even achievable would be warmly received.

Comment: "*my current output for the <synopsis></synopsis> elements is obviously a continual block of text without spaces*" No, I don't think so. Perhaps that's what you see rendered in a browser, but that doesn't mean the underlying code is output that way. --  Anyway, your question is about *tokenizing*. See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597058/how-to-split-string-in-xml/23598237#23598237 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524975/xslt-tokenizing-template-to-italicize-and-bold-xml-element-text/29537101#29537101 (many others can be found).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it should be necessary to modify your original XML input. You can simply use the line-feed character as the delimiter (and apply some normalizing to the remaining white-spaces):

```
<xsl:template match="synopsis">
    Synopsis: <span style="color:#38A930">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </span>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&#10;'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter))" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
            </p>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Spot on. Works a treat!!

Comment: To your knowledge, has this particular template ever had any issues when rendering through the Google Chrome browser? I've noticed that instead of the template providing a paragraph after the line-feed (like IE and Firefox), it's occurring after every word instead, although this could be as a result of my CSS setup?

Comment: @Joel I don't have Chrome installed, so I cannot say. It shouldn't make any difference, since this is pure and simple XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

As [michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k) revealed in his useful comment (above), the solution to this problem revolved around *tokenizing*, which is something I hadn't come across before using XSLT.

Utilising michael.hor257k's handy delimiter based solution in this post (accepted answer) - [XSLT - Tokenizing template to italicize and bold XML element text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524975/xslt-tokenizing-template-to-italicize-and-bold-xml-element-text) - I was able to output my element's text into separated paragraphs.

**Updated XML: (Notice the asterisks surrounding each part of my text I want to convert to paragraphs)**

```
    <synopsis>
         *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone is the first novel in the Harry Potter series and J. K. Rowling's debut novel.* 

         *The plot follows Harry Potter, a young wizard who discovers his magical heritage as he makes close friends and a few enemies in his first year at the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.* 

         *With the help of his friends, Harry faces an attempted comeback by the dark wizard Lord Voldemort, who killed Harry's parents, but failed to kill Harry when he was just a year old.*
   </synopsis>
```

**XSLT Template:**

```
<xsl:template name="paragraphs">
<xsl:param name="text"/>
<xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'*'"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter) and contains(substring-after($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)"/>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
        </p>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="paragraphs">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(substring-after($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**Call the XSLT Template:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="/dataroot/bookstore/book">
    <xsl:call-template name="paragraphs">
         <xsl:with-param name="text" select="synopsis"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**HTML Output:**

```
    <p>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone is the first novel in the Harry Potter series and J. K. Rowling's debut novel.</p>

    <p>The plot follows Harry Potter, a young wizard who discovers his magical heritage as he makes close friends and a few enemies in his first year at the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.</p>

    <p>With the help of his friends, Harry faces an attempted comeback by the dark wizard Lord Voldemort, who killed Harry's parents, but failed to kill Harry when he was just a year old.</p>
```

... And one happy customer!!

**I've also made this simplified XML Transform to show the paragraph output in action** - http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh2B